# This file is part of the project. Please include it in the appropriate file build(build.gradle, CMakeLists,txt or Android.mk and sync the project

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am new to using NDK in android. I am trying to write the native code in a new .c file. I am getting this error when ever I try to sync the .c file.

THis is the Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := test-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test-jni.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

gradle.build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "poc.aditya.com.hello_jni"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',     {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The sync completes with no errors but the message in the test-jni.c file wont go away

Comment: Could the path to the CMakeLists.txt not be accurate?

Answer (score 1):

"This file is part of the project." means the file is just created but the build system(build.gradle, CMakeLists,txt or Android.mk) has not put it into the project,so it can't be build.Based on your question,you use the CMake,so make sure your CMakeLists is right with your new c/c++ file path.
In Android Studio 3.3.1,My MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public native String stringFromJNI();

}
```

when i use the "alt+enter" to make the new native-lib.c,it creates in the "src/main/jni",but I put CMakeLists.txt in the "src/main/cpp" and the CMakeLists.txt is:# Provides a relative path to your source file(s).

```
native-lib.c
```

It says "a relative path",so it not in the "src/main/jni" it shoud be in the "src/main/cpp", I just move the new native-lib.c to the "src/main/cpp", then try again the gradle, it will work.